# Find the Antiderivative $\int \frac{1}{f(x)f''(x)}\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration

$$
\int \frac{1}{f(x)f''(x)}\mathrm{d}x
$$

Does this antiderivative have a closed formula?

I am asking with respect to a particular application, where  $f(x):=\sqrt{1-x^2}+x\arcsin{x}$ (therefore $f'(x)=\arcsin{x}$ and $f''(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$).

Comment: I don't think that you could find a closed for this one.

Comment: Doesn't hold for [log](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+1%2F(log+x+*+-x%5E(-2)))